# How to change application language?

Tags: android, kotlin, locale

I'm trying to change my application language in runtime. I have checked several posts and my code now looks like:

```
if(position == 0){//Position 0 of an array to select the language
  val locale = Locale("es_ES")
  val config = applicationContext.resources.configuration
  config.setLocale(locale)
  applicationContext.createConfigurationContext(config)
}
```

I have a values-es directory where I have my own strings.xml file with strings translated. Anyway, it seems like it doesn't change anything.

I repeat I tried and checked a lot of posts in Stack Overflow but I don't know where I'm failing. 
Thanks in advance, I'm open to any question due to my bad english.

Second try:

I've been tryng and now my code looks like this:

```
val locale = Locale("es")
Locale.setDefault(locale)
val config = applicationContext.resources.configuration
config.setLocale(locale)
applicationContext.resources.configuration.setTo(config)
Log.d("Configuration",config.toString())
Log.d("Language",config.locales.toLanguageTags())
```

And the debug messages are :

```
D/Configuration: {1.0 310mcc260mnc [es] ldltr sw411dp w683dp h387dp 420dpi nrml land finger qwerty/v/v -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1794, 1080) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1794, 1080) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} s.40}


D/Language: es
```

But my strings doesn't change and my app keeps using the strings(en) file.

```
val config = application.applicationContext.resources.configuration
                    val locale = Locale("es")
                    Locale.setDefault(locale)
                    config.setLocale(locale)
                    application.applicationContext.resources.configuration.setLocale(locale)
                    application.applicationContext.resources.configuration.updateFrom(config)
                    finish()
                    startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is weird, i had the same problem yesterday and with this code works for me.

```
private fun changeLanguage(lenguage:String){
    val newLocale = Locale(lenguage)
    val activityRes = resources
    val activityConf = activityRes.configuration
    activityConf.setLocale(newLocale)
    activityRes.updateConfiguration(activityConf, activityRes.displayMetrics)

    val applicationRes = applicationContext.resources
    val applicationConf = applicationRes.configuration
    applicationConf.setLocale(newLocale)
    baseContext.createConfigurationContext(
        applicationConf
    )
}
```

and I use like this

```
goToLocations("en")
```

or

```
goToLocations("es")
```

Cheers